# GitHub windows 7 sh.exe has stopped working

Tags: windows, git, github

Every time I run an operation from the command line for GitHub for windows I get a popup that says sh.exe has stopped working. The UI seems to work correctly. The command line is using the sh.exe that comes with GIT. Can't seem to find anything that indicates why this won't work. I'm on git version 1.9.5.github.0

```
where sh.exe
C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin\sh.exe

Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: sh.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5493b035
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18247
  Fault Module Timestamp:   521ea8e7
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 0002e89b
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 1399
  Additional Information 2: 13999f650f320d7991b1e9a99014be23
  Additional Information 3: a184
  Additional Information 4: a184c4b74a6985d371aaed4321c83a0e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to run:

```
ansicon -u sh.exe
```

If this fixes your issue, I recommend trying this:

```
Change the Rails command line / Git bash shortcuts to point to syswow64 instead of
system32 or vice-verse. If that doesn't work you can install/re-install 32-bit AND 64-bit
version of ansicon and then go from there.
```

You should be able to find more help [here](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/issues/46).

Comment: I didn't need to change the git bash shortcuts. The change with ansicon appears to have resolved the issue.

Comment: This fixed our issue. I have no idea why (didn't have to change the shortcuts either)